# Why double parameter constructor begins with an explicit keyword?

Tags: c++, explicit

My buddy and I have been recently reading leveldb source code. And we encounter this problem. In leveldb [db/skiplist.h](https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/source/browse/db/skiplist.h?r=bc1ee4d25e09b04e074db330a41f54ef4af0e31b) file, there is a constructor declaration:

```
explicit SkipList(Comparator cmp, Arena* arena);
```

I know explicit constructor with single parameter means no implicit type conversion for constructor parameter. But what does double parameters constructor with explicit keyword mean? 
Is it new rule of C++11?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the exact declaration? Has `arena` no default value?

Comment: @Gorpik I dont know if the OP has exactly the same interface but look [here](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/source/browse/db/skiplist.h?r=bc1ee4d25e09b04e074db330a41f54ef4af0e31b).

Comment: The C++ "explicit" keyword is used to avoid implicit cast

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi Thanks for the link. Line 46 is what I quote.

Comment: @alexbuisson yes, as I mentions in my question. But what about mutiple parameter constructor?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With C++11, you can use *braced-init-lists* in place of some other expressions, and that makes a difference. For instance, you can use them in return statements:

```
SkipList foo() {
    return {{}, nullptr}; //does not compile with explicit constructor
    return SkipList{{}, nullptr}; //compiles with or without explicit constructor
}
```

Comment: By uniform initialization You mean initializing multiple parameter like initializing an array?

Comment: @lulyon, Uniform initialization generally results from using braces. You can use them to call constructors, as shorthand for `TypeName()`, and to eliminate the most vexing parse. It's actually quite a significant feature of C++11. You should look up some information on it.

Comment: This is called *list initialization*

Comment: @M.M, Thanks, I changed it to use *braced-init-list* instead to match the "top level" of wording, even though it is list-initialized when all is said and done.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this constructor originally had a default argument (or was adapted from a single-argument constructor). There's not that many cases where you'd actually want to disable copy-list-initialization.

Comment: @T.C., True, I guess these aren't all that common in the wild.